# hide commands from xtrace

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to hide a command from the output with xtrace on (`set -o xtrace`)?

In DOS, the technique is to turn `echo on` but prefix the hidden commands with the `@` symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never seen a similar trick in bash, but you can sometimes use subshells to temporarily enable tracing for commands you're interested in:

```
echo "This command is not traced"
(
  set -x
  echo "This command is traced"
)
echo "No longer traced"
```

If subshells are not suitable because you want to modify the environment, you can `set -x` and then `set +x`, but that leaves you with the artifacts of tracing `set +x` commands.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
# At start of script, or where xtrace may be enabled:
[[ "$SHELLOPTS" =~ xtrace ]] && xtrace_on=1

# Later
set +o xtrace
# Your untraced code here
[[ "$xtrace_on" ]] && set -o xtrace
```